# How does Kinetica's backup/restore facility work in Kinetica KAgent?

Tags: kinetica

What exactly happens under the cover?  Does it create a new complete snap shot of the full data set each time?  Is there some type of differential comparison with the last snapshot?  What is the state of the system during the backup?

Answer (score 1):

The first time a backup is made, it is an rsync from one folder to another.  After that, we "copy" all files in the previous backup to a new folder via hard links and then rsync from persist to that new folder to update.  Cold is separate if we need to discuss that, but S3 and HDFS are backed up at the same time.
Please see our documentation on backup & restore: https://www.kinetica.com/docs/gpudbAdmin/backing_up_kinetica.html

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer with a link to further detail, and welcome to the community!